# Transform to create barrel effect seen in Apple's Camera app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to recreate the barrel effect that can be seen on the camera mode picker below:

[image: iOS7 Camera app]
<sub>(source: [androidnova.org](http://www.androidnova.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ios7_camera-100041271-medium.jpg))</sub>

**Do I have to use OpenGL in order to achieve this effect? What is the best approach?**

I found a great library on GitHub that can be used to achieve this effect (https://github.com/Ciechan/BCMeshTransformView), but unfortunately it doesn't support animation and is therefore not usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet Apple used CGMeshTransform. It's just like BCMeshTransform, except it is a private API and fully integrates with Core Graphics. BCMeshTransformView was born when a developer discovered this.

The only easy option I see is:

Use CALayer.transform, which is a CATransform3D. You can use this to simulate the barrel effect you want by adjusting the z position and y rotation of each item on the barrel. Also add a semitransparent dark gradient (CAGradientLayer) to the wheel to simulate the effect of choices getting darker towards the edges. This will be simple to do, but won't look as smooth and realistic as an actual 3D barrel. Maybe it will look good enough to create a convincing illusion though? (To enable 3D transforms, you need to enable depth by using view.layer.transform.m34 = 1/500.f or similar)

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/introduction-to-3d-drawing-in-core-animation-part-1/

The hardest option is using a custom OpenGL view that makes a barrel shape and applies your contents on top of it as a texture. I would expect that you run into most of the complexities behind creating BCMeshTransformView, and have difficulty supporting animations just like BCMeshTransformView did.

You may still be able to use BCMeshTransformView though. BCMeshTransformView is slow at processing content animations such as color changes, but is very fast at processing geometry changes. So you could use it to do a barrel effect, as long as you define the barrel effect entirely in terms of mesh geometry changes (instead of as content changes like using a scroll view or adjusting subview positions). You would need to do gesture handling + scrolling yourself instead of using UIScrollView though, which is tricky and tedious to get right.

Considering the options, I would want to fudge it by using 3D transforms, then move to other options only if I can't create a convincing illusion using 3D transforms.

Comment: Does BCMeshTransform use Apple's private API's? Will using BCMeshTransform possibly get one's app rejected?

Comment: @i2Fluffy No, BCMeshTransform uses OpenGL. It does not use Apple's private API